# Getting 404's for rendered .coffee files

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, gruntjs, yeoman

I have a test node.js/angular app that uses the yeoman angular-generator.  However, I am having problems serving back the rendered .js files from the original .coffee files.

The js files are being rendered and saved to APP_ROOT/.tmp, but any requests for the js files results in a 404.

What is needed (within the Gruntfile?) to allow for the js files to be returned?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this issue somehow indeed related to AngularJS?

Comment: I don't think so.  The angular files are being rendered to the .tmp path, but the server responds with 404's on the requests.

Comment: Using `grunt server` you should get all files from `.tmp/`, that includes the CoffeeScript files.

Comment: I am already doing exactly that, which is why I am assuming that there is a Gruntfile config that is responsible for the making it happen.  If I could find a working example I am pretty sure I could figure out what is missing on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things are working now. The end fix was something was to add an additional static middleware to the app.js file, which was something I had already tried, but it is possible that the path was off causing the *fix* not to work.

#### app.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '.tmp')));
```

When I first added ~line 2 the app.js folder was moved into the app_root/server folder with the following

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', '.tmp')));
```

which for some reason wasn't working.  That teaches me for moving files around